# Is there still research going on for Lebesgue Integral / Measure

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Just curious on whether Lebesgue Integration / Lebesgue Measure is still an ongoing research area, or is already a mature topic like Calculus where no new research is going on?

Are there any open questions on Lebesgue Integration?

Thanks!

Comment: is there really no research going on into calculus?  I was just curious.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton At least not that I know of, e.g. no professor will put "Calculus" under his research interest. Probably yes though if we consider differential geometry or differential manifolds as calculus.

Comment: I don't know enough to answer the question, but there is a Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications which at least has articles that appear to talk about measure theory.